# Fake URL Shortener

Tags: cakephp-3.5

I want to redirect `www.myhost.com/g/:id` to `www.myhost.com/jobs/view/:id`. Currently the following code does that fine:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/g/:id',
    ['controller' => 'Jobs', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['pass' => ['id'], 'status' => 301, 'persist' => ['id']]
);
```

However, in the addressbar it still shows `www.myhost.com/g/:id`. I'd like it to show the full URL (`www.myhost.com/jobs/view/:id`), not the 'shortened' URL.

How would I adjust the code to do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Router::connect](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#namespace-Cake%5CRouting) is a way of connecting one route to another, without a full redirect.

If you're wanting  redirect a user and have that exposed to them, you can use [Router::redirect()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages).  It automatically will set the 301 status.

```
$routes->redirect(
    '/g/:id', 
    ['controller' => 'Jobs', 'action' => 'view'], 
    ['pass' => ['id'], 'persist' => true]
);
```

Comment: Reading your answer made me realise that I could try [`$routes->redirect`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing) which solved my problem. Now it's just adding a silly `?id=:id` at the end. So it's turning `http://www.myhost.com/g/:id` into `http://www.myhost.com/jobs/view/:id?id=:id` where `:id` is the actual integer value being thrown around. If you update your answer, I'll add upvote and accept.

Comment: Can you just update the question so `redirect`'s arguments look like this: `'/g/:id',
    ['controller' => 'Jobs', 'action' => 'view'], 
    ['pass' => ['id'], 'persist' => true]` because this is the exact code that worked